# Регулярка для номера телефона

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Всем привет 
Помогите написать регулярку для номера телефона 
С такой вот маской

```
{"mask": "(999) 999-9999"}
```

Пытался написать,  но что то явно не так(

```
var re = /^\d[\d\(\)\ -]{4,14}\d$/;

var re = /^(\s*)?(\+)?([- _():=+]?\d[- _():=+]?){10,14}(\s*)?$/;
```

Пример того,  как устроен обработчик

```
$(".giftSubmit").click(
        function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var parent = $(this).parent();
            var input = parent.find('input');
            var re = /^\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}-\d{4}$/;
            var valid = re.test(input);
            console.log(valid);
            if (valid) {
                sendAjaxForm('formModal', 'giftForm', 'php/request.php',$(this).attr('name'));
                return false;
            }  else {
                const _telError = parent.find('.terError');
                _telError.addClass('active');
                setTimeout( () => {
                    _telError.removeClass('active')
                }, 4000)
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Пример на кодпен https://codepen.io/SkipTyler/pen/YjmNYe

Comment: а может так `\(\d{3}\)\s*\d{3}-\d{4}`

Comment: `var re = /^\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}-\d{4}$/`

Comment: @KoVadim eslinter пишет что ошибка Webpack не пропускает(

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Почему то не работает. Сейчас дополню код. 
как у меня все работает.

Comment: Ищите баг в этом коде, регулярка - то, что нужно.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew моет быть проблема в .test()?

Comment: Нет, скорее в `input`, но точно не в `var re = /^\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}-\d{4}$/; var valid = re.test(...);`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81819/discussion-between-skip-tyler-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score -1):

Верное решение:

```
var re = /^[\d()\ \-]{4,14}\d$/; 
var valid = re.test(input.val());
```

Comment: [Вы уверены?](https://regex101.com/r/l1jmFP/1)

Comment: Да, по сей день работает.

Comment: Это решение (`/^[\d()\ \-]{4,14}\d$/`) не соответствует заявленной проблеме, ваша маска - `"(999) 999-9999"`. `/^[\d()\ \-]{4,14}\d$/` никак ей не соответствует.